# What is utmu parameter in google analytics __utm.gif request?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to make the google analytic __utm.gif request using php. I have broken all the variables and the only one which I don't know about is **utmu** parameter. It is not documented anywhere.

When I see a pageview tracking request it is appended to the end of request as `&utmu=qB~`
While doing ecommerce tracking it is appended as `&utmu=qBAL~`

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bitmap of all of the methods used to build the request.

Source: http://glucik.blogspot.com/2011/02/utmu-google-analytics-request-parameter.html

Answer (score 1):

`utmu` doesn't actually contain anything of external meaning. Google uses it to store some internal values that help them improve `ga.js`. It's not required to make any functionality work, so, your PHP code doesn't need to account for it.

However, you should know there are already a few long-standing PHP-based Google Analytics projects, like [Server Side Google Analytics (SSGA)](http://code.google.com/p/serversidegoogleanalytics/), as well as the semi-official [Google Analytics for Mobile PHP](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/#php) and [PHPGA](http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/).